# Convert GeoPDF to GeoTIFF

Tags: pdf, geolocation, geospatial, tiff, geo

Does anyone have an idea about converting GeoPDF to GeoTIFF?
I tried GDAL by but GDAL is not building with PDF support, I got success with GeoTIFF but it's not getting compiled with GeoPDF.

Does anyone have any other tricks/Ideas to convert GeoPDF to GeoTIFF/GeoJSON?

Comment: Can you a link to an example file? Also, GeoTIFF is used for raster data, GeoJSON for vector data (perhaps most likely to be what you have?). So do you actually want GeoTiff? And can you show what *code* you have tried (after all, this is a coding site; for GIS questions see gis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

gdal_translate pdf fileneme geotiff filename -of GTiff

Here is a detailed process for the conversion: https://opengislab.com/blog/tag/GeoPDF+to+GeoTiff

It is wrapped in a bat file for conversion in this repo: https://github.com/tbugg/GeoPDF_to_GeoTIFF

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Here is the command to use:

gdal_translate <geopdf filename> <output geotiff filename> -of GTiff

The link provided above has all the options to use with this command to do the conversion, along with the option to install the required libraries.

Comment: Will do. @IanCampbell.

Comment: Also, ArcMap as a tool to convert PDF to Tiff, if you have the license. It is part of the Conversion Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with digital mapping for decades, I suggest you may be disappointed by this task and goal.

GeoPDF is a superset of PDF with geoMARK refs so not all data is likely to be transferred out into the Tiff image but I would suspect Esri®ArcMap/GIS is likely to do it best. but GDAL is open source.

The US Library of Congress [review](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000522.shtml) includes

"Many GIS applications can import and display GeoPDF files and extract layers or convert a GeoPDF map to another format but are not able to reproduce the advanced functionality of the GeoPDF Toolbar."

Basically as it is proprietary closed source, then FOSS geoPDF is unlikely in reverse engineering to produce GeoTiff of much value, it is best to use the source GeoTiffs that were used for GeoPDF enhanced input.

Note the original authoritative [article](http://www.rasteredge.com/gallery/c38/441/) is headed

***"Readers are cautioned that this reformat is complex and tedious, with significant learning curves for most people."***

One good source to start with is that USGS one

https://apps.nationalmap.gov/raster-conversion/

In turn leads to

https://apps.nationalmap.gov/raster-conversion/gdal-installation-and-setup-guide.html

Which then shows how to install **gdal** to run scripts with troubleshooting tips about newer versions etc. so **for example today, a 5 day old pre-built windows binary** suitable for use in python 3.6-3.9 is here

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal/files?sort=basename&sort_order=desc